# How to populate WinForms TreeView from xml file, regardless the number of children and grandchildren

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Sorry if this has been posted before, but all the solutions i could find only addressed XML files with on layer of children.

I have a form displaying a treeview. Instead of having to edit directly in the code, i want to create an XML file, and populate my treeview from that. My XML is similar to this:

```
<Root>
  <Element>
    <ChildElement>
      <GrandChildElement></GrandChildElement>
      <GrandChildElement></GrandChildElement>
    </ChildElement>
    <ChildElement>
      <GrandChildElement></GrandChildElement>
      <GrandChildElement></GrandChildElement>
    </ChildElement>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ChildElement>
      <GrandChildElement></GrandChildElement>
      <GrandChildElement></GrandChildElement>
    </ChildElement>
    <ChildElement>
      <GrandChildElement></GrandChildElement>
      <GrandChildElement></GrandChildElement>
    </ChildElement>
  </Element>
</Root>
```

The GrandChildElements, is the clickable nodes in my treeview, which can be used to select different things. The rest is used to visually categorize them.

So far i haven't managed to find a way to include the GrandChildElements. Populating it without the GrandChildElements, can be done through recursion like this:

```
private void treeView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("treeNodes.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    xmldoc.Load(fs);
    XmlNode xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];
    tvKortskab.Nodes.Clear();
    tvKortskab.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xmldoc.DocumentElement.Name));
    TreeNode tNode = tvKortskab.Nodes[0];
    AddNode(xmlnode, tNode);
}


 private void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
 {
     XmlNode xNode;
     TreeNode tNode;
     XmlNodeList childNodes;
     XmlNodeList subChildNodes;
     if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
     {
         childNodes = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
         for (int i = 0; i <= childNodes.Count - 1; i++)
         {
             xNode = childNodes[i];
             inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
             tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
             AddNode(xNode, tNode);
         }
         else
         {
             inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();
         }
 }
```

I have tried nesting a loop inside that, checking if the childNodes had children, and then adding those. That worked, but also added a bunch of empty and duplicate nodes.

Comment: Can you be more specifiy, why the grandchildelement is not working? From what I see about recursion, it looks as if it should work.

Comment: please do note your Grandchildren nodes do not have a value. is that what you meant ?

Comment: I see it works, but as the grandchild has no sub nodes, the text gets ovewrriden with "inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea was correct and you did the right thing.

But at the `else` statement you did something wrong.
You say, that the "GrandChildElement" should show the `InnerText` and this text is empty, so you get an empty element. You need to use the `Name` property instead.

```
if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
{
    childNodes = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
    for (int i = 0; i <= childNodes.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        xNode = childNodes[i];
        inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
        tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
        AddNode(xNode, tNode);
    }
}
else
{
    inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand what you meant.

Since your GrandChildren nodes are empty,following line would show an empty value there.

```
inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();
```

One possible solution is to show the node name if innerText is empty.

```
inTreeNode.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(inXmlNode.InnerText)? inXmlNode.Name :  inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();
```

PS: Btw, you had a possible typo here

```
XmlNode xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];
```

This needs to be

```
XmlNode xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[0];
```

**Earlier Output**

[image]

**New Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with everything but the part about the typo. If i set it to index 0, it just shows "xml" in the list with no nodes. 

But you are right, at first it seems like a mistake to ignore the first index.